# Finding all lines between multiple points with common attribute using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro

I have a line layer, which is divided by points with a common attribute. Now I want to assign the attribute of points to all lines which are between these points. The line layer can also be used as a network layer. It contains no gaps.

Is there a solution for this problem using ArcGIS Pro?

Img 1: Screenshot of a part of the network with the boundary points.

[image: Screenshot of a part of the line layer with the boundary points.]

Img 2: Screenshot of the desired result. (Manually created)

[image: Screenshot of the desired result. (Manually created)]

Comment: It's not particularly clear what you have done in the second image, why are the lines left of your points unselected? I think you need to zoom in and describe EXACTLY what you have done. But as a first best guess you could try constructing lines between your points and then use that line to select the lines _between_ the points?

Comment: Thank you very much. In image 2, I selected the lines by hand. This image should only show the desired result. How should I construct these lines?

Comment: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/points-to-line.htm